# Where does the setFrameAutosaveName method save the window's position?

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults, nswindow

I know that Cocoa could save a window's position in user defaults using `setFrameAutosaveName:` or `saveFrameUsingName:` method.

But where is user defaults?

Is it in the fixed place for every application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is stored in your applications user defaults. For each window it creates a default with a fixed prefix of `NSWindow Frame` and appends your window's autosave name. Example:

```
defaults read my.app.identifier
    ...
    "NSWindow Frame MyWindowAutoSaveName" = "386 174 1811 1080 0 0 2560 1418 ";
    ...
```

Comment: Where is the exact path for "applications user defaults" in your mention?

Comment: Typically in `~/Library/Preferences/my.app.identifier.plist`, where `~` is your home directory and `my.app.identifier` the identifier of the app, for example `com.apple.Mail`. Of course you should rarely if ever directly access that file. From the command line use the `defaults` command, and in Cocoa apps you'd use `NSUserDefaults` and friends.

Comment: Got it. Really appreciate that.

Comment: Please note that one should not manually change anything in `~/Library/Preferences` anymore in recent OS X versions, as the system keeps an in-memory database of defaults. The only safe way to access the defaults from the command line (terminal) is via the `defaults` command, see `man defaults` for help with that.

Answer (score 1):

For sandboxed apps:

```
~/Library/Containers/my.app.identifier/Data/Library/Preferences/my.app.identifier.plist
```

For non-sandboxed apps:

```
~/Library/Preferences/my.app.identifier.plist
```

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/a/907899/131965